# Something I don't understand about NoSQL (M:N relationships)

Tags: mongodb, many-to-many, nosql

I admit it... I lack a lot of theory concepts when it comes to NoSQL world.

I was thinking about porting some simple apps using Java+MySQL to NodeJS+MongoDB (I found the mongoose ORM which looks really cool).

One of the first thing I find really hard and less documented is mapping many-to-many relationships.

I first read the Mongo-DOCS: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Schema+Design

... then lurked around for some real-world info, and I found lots of q&a like that: [Modeling data on a many-to-many join in Mongo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9720464/modeling-data-on-a-many-to-many-join-in-mongo)

There's the way to achieve a M:N, cool! But then I read something that really scares and disappoint me: " *Honestly I would just go with a relational database if you find yourself needing joins.* "

OK! I get the point but.... imagine I have the common User + Roles + UserRoles many-to-many schema and I use **embedding**, I mean, I do not use another table-schema for roles, I only use User with all roles data in it

I need to:

- query for all users in the db, reading their role data, too;
- query for all roles just available in the db, for example, for choosing the role associated in user creation;

The first point is trivial, but what about the second?

You will tell me that I need another table-schema "Roles" and store in "User" the roles array, with IDs of roles but then, you will tell me that this is a relational world!

Are you tellin' me that it's not suitable for a NoSQL db? So **what** would be?

Comment: What is the point? Either you adjust your data model to what MongoDB supports or you denormalize your data or your perform multiple queries...what is the problem?

Comment: If you care to explain your English a bit better and maybe give us some examples I am sure we can help you a lot more. I am particulary confused with the English used to actually describe the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your options are:

- denormalize your data
- perform multiple queries
- use the MongoDB aggregation framework (if applicable here)
- don't use MongoDB

Make your choice...

Comment: in facts, my question was a "best practices" request! Can you add to your answer some more basic concepts (e.g. pro and cons for each way) please?

Comment: This isn't much of answer if I am honest...I mean you even guess the needs with the aggregation framework, no question based facts are answered here so not sure why it should have been marked...

Answer (score 3):

### You may need to denormalize your data.

The way to do it correctly is to **look at your use cases and design your database accordingly**.
This means that you will have to think about the usage scenarios.

### The users/roles example

Let's think about the use cases.

- Quickly tell what roles are a user in
- Query all the roles so that you can pick roles for a user when you create or edit a user.

I would do it like this:

- Store the roles on the users as you do now
- Also store all the roles in a separate collection

This will fulfill all the requirements correctly.
Obviously, because of the denormalization, you will need to take special care when updating/renaming the roles.

Comment: How would "special care" be implemented? Does mongodb provide tools for doing this?

Comment: @Asad I'm not sure if there are tools for this. What I meant is that most likely you will have to take care of it yourself. I think you will need to implement it in your application code.